# How to avoid navigation in outside of the popped up drawer

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility

Hi I'm currently working on a reactjs web application and trying to provide accessibility features in web pages. In one page there's a drawer popping up once a button clicked, and I wanted to make sure the tab navigation only through the drawer without going outside of the drawer when it expanded. How can I do that?

Here I have attached the screen shot of the page including the expanded drawer.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend writing a keyboard handler in JavaScript to restrict tab order to the pop-out "drawer" (or modal as I'd call it).

Hidde de Vries wrote an excellent short tutorial on this, see [here](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2017-01-29-using-javascript-to-trap-focus-in-an-element).

I adapted this very slightly:

```
// Function to trap tab movement to a specific container element
trapFocusInArtworkModal = function (el) {

    // Gather all focusable elements in a list
    var query = "a[href]:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), input[type='email']:not([disabled]), input[type='text']:not([disabled]), input[type='radio']:not([disabled]), input[type='checkbox']:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), [tabindex='0']"
    var focusableEls = el.querySelectorAll(query);
    var firstFocusableEl = focusableEls[0];
    var lastFocusableEl = focusableEls[focusableEls.length - 1];

    // Add the key listener to the modal container to listen for Tab,
    // Left Arrow, Right Arrow, Enter and Escape
    el.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        var isTabPressed = (e.key === "Tab" || e.keyCode === KEYCODE_TAB);
        var isEscPressed = (e.key === "Escape" || e.keyCode === KEYCODE_ESCAPE);

        // Define behaviour for Tab or Shift+Tab
        if (isTabPressed) {
            // Shift+Tab
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                if (document.activeElement === firstFocusableEl) {
                    // Move keyboard focus to the last focusable element in the container
                    lastFocusableEl.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            
            // Tab
            else {
                if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableEl) {
                    // Move keyboard focus to the first focusable element in the container
                    firstFocusableEl.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Define behaviour for Escape
        if (isEscPressed) {
            // This will close out the modal when the Escape key is pressed
            // by clicking the modal's close link/button
            el.querySelector("a").click();
        }
    });
};

// Find the modal
var modal = document.querySelector("[role='dialog']");

// Attach the trap keyboard function to the modal
trapFocusInArtworkModal(modal);
```

You can then attach the code to run when the page has loaded.